# if image exists show image else show different image + image path

Tags: php

```
<?php $img = shellImage($data[$y]->kunena_avatar_rows[$z]->avatar, 'noresize'); ?>
<?php if ($img->exist) : ?>
    <?php echo $img->draw(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <img src="media/avatars/resized/size200/nophoto.jpg">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Trying to figure out how to add a path to the image.

The value in the database for the image is like this users/avatar.jpg and the full path for the image would be `media/avatars/resized/size200/avatar.jpg`

Comment: What do you mean by `$img->draw()`?  Are you trying to output raw image data or something?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php $img = shellImage($data[$y]->kunena_avatar_rows[$z]->avatar, 'noresize'); ?>
 <?php if ($img->exist) : ?>
     <?php echo  str_replace("users/", "media/avatars/resized/size200/", $img->draw()"); ?>
 <?php else: ?>
   <img src="media/avatars/resized/size200/nophoto.jpg">
 <?php endif; ?>
```